# Why can't I install LAMP stack on Amazon ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I try to follow this tutorial from amazon (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

I get a series of errors:

```
Error: php56-pdo conflicts with php-pdo-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.29-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.29-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-process conflicts with php-process-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56 conflicts with php-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-xml conflicts with php-xml-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php-mysql conflicts with php56-mysqlnd-5.6.8-1.111.amzn1.x86_64
```

This was a brand new amazon linux ami and I'm following their tutorial line for line. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to decide if you want to install php 5.3 or 5.6, the packages conflict with each other.

Comment: yeah, i want php 5 but when i run yum remove php-common and then yum install php55 i get the same error

Comment: Do yum remove php*. This will remove all old php packages.

Comment: I still get an error: yum remove php
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No Match for argument: php
No Packages marked for removal

Comment: Make sure you include the wildcard * in your command. It should look like this `yum remove php*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install php5.6 version , you are try install old version .

Try this : 
     yum install php56-pdo

Answer (score 0):

You must remove all package that conflicts as php-pdo, php-common, httpd-tools, httpd...

```
Ex: sudo yum remove php* httpd httpd-tools
```